# WP submenu extra item

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to WordPress. I'm having trouble with the menu and submenu.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'manage_rider_menu');

function manage_rider_menu() {
add_menu_page( 'Manage Riders', 'Manage Riders', 'manage_options', 'manage-rider',         'my_magic_function');
add_submenu_page('manage-rider', 'Add Rider Information', 'Add Rider', 'manage_options', 'add-rider', 'add_rider_options');
}
```

I was expecting for: **Manage Riders** -> **Add Rider**

What I get: **Manage Riders** -> **Manage Riders** | **Add Rider**

My question is how to remove the 'Manage Riders' from the submenu?

Thank you. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a workaround for my problem. I just want to share it

```
add_menu_page( 'Manage Riders', 'Manage Riders', 'manage_options', 'add-rider', 'my_magic_function');
add_submenu_page('add-rider', 'Add Rider Information', 'Add Rider', 'manage_options', 'add-rider', 'add_rider_options');
```